# Spring’s BulkOperations execute() doesn’t actually modify document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

During Spring job loading I am using Spirng’s BulkOperations to update documents in my Mongo database using multiple updateOne models.
`BulkOperations bulkOps = template.bulkOps(BulkMode.UNORDERED, MyClass.class);`

And multiple `bulkOps.updateOne(query, update);`

With `bulkOps.execute()` at the end. At the end the `BulkWiteResult result = bulkOps.execute();` returns 7 matched documents (as it should) and 7 modified, but no changes in the document inside of mongo are done. You have any idea why? Is the upsert needed?

Comment: Any solution for this? I have same problem. Strangely, it executes on one environment, but now on other two. I use Java 8, Spring 2.3.0.RELEASE (spring-data-mongodb 3.0.0, but I tried also with 3.4.6).<br>
No exceptions at all. It executes, but no changes in database.

Comment: I found out what was a problem in my code. I use BulkOperations inside Mongock @ChangeUnit. I have multiple change units and last one is change of collection name. Also, I changed collection name inside entity class. When doing `execute` BulkOperations do `mongoOperations.execute(collectionName, this::bulkWriteTo)` and it seems he gets `collectionName` from entity class. When I reverted collection name it startd working.